EntityManager" is null in JPA
persistence.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="filePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/file</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/file"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="12345"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


Bean class
import dao.FileDAO;
import entity.Filee;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Part;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;



@Named
@SessionScoped
public class FileManager implements Serializable{
    
    private Filee file;
    
    private FileDAO fdao;
    private List<Filee> list;
    private Part doc;
    
    private String uploadTo="C:\\files\\";
    
    public void upload() {
    try {
        InputStream input = doc.getInputStream();
        File f = new File(uploadTo + doc.getSubmittedFileName());
        Files.copy(input, f.toPath());

        Filee newFile = new Filee();
        newFile.setPath(f.getParent());
        newFile.setName(f.getName());
        newFile.setType(doc.getContentType());

        

        getFdao().create(newFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage());
    }
}

AbstractDao

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> implements Serializable{
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
    
}

FileDAO
import entity.Filee;
import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class FileDAO extends AbstractFacade<Filee> {

 
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "filePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public FileDAO() {
        super(Filee.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}


I want to use jpa in my Java jsf project but I get an error.
When I run this code I get entitymenager null error. how can I solve this error.
eror message:
Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()" because the return value of "dao.AbstractFacade.getEntityManager()" is null

I'm new at this. Can you help me? What exactly should I do?  @BalusC

getFdao() might be the culprit. How do you create the FileDAO there? If you instantiate it by new, then em won't be injected. Best is to inject FileDAO into FileManager

You should have @EJB FileDAO fileDao; in your FileManager

thank you I tried this and it worked @ArjanTijms

  @EJB FileDAO fileDao;

It worked when I edited it this way
